# How can I pull user input data as type "date" into my SQL database using PHP 7?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, date, post

I am trying to INSERT user input data in `type="date"` format into my SQL database using PHP. However, when I use the `$_POST` method to pull the data from the HTML form into my PHP file for processing, the **date value** does not come through but other values do. Here is my code:

HTML (reduced code)

```
<form action"process.php" method="POST" >
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name>
  <input type="date" id="dateOfBirth" name="dateOfBirth" placeholder="2020-01-01" >
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitButton" >
</form>
```

PHP (reduced code)

```
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$dateOfBirth = $_POST['dateOfBirth'];

if (!empty($fname)) {
    die("First Name is empty! <br>");
} else {
    echo "First Name is not empty! <br>";
}

if (!empty($dateOfBirth)) {
    die("Date of Birth is empty! <br>");
} else {
    echo "Date of Birth is not empty! <br>";
}
```

The outputs from the PHP file are:

```
First Name is not empty!
Date of Birth is empty!
```

The `fname` data comes through fine using the $_POST method but the `dateOfBirth` data is not getting pulled through $_POST to the PHP page at all. Thoughts?

Comment: It should be `if( empty($dateOfBirth))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic for your two `if (!empty(...))` is inverted, so actually, `fname` does *NOT* come though, but `dateOfBirth` does.

`$_POST['fname']` doesn't exist, your element has a name of `firstname` and since your logic is inverted, it *looks like* `fname` is set. Change your code to

```
$fname = $_POST['firstname'];
$dateOfBirth = $_POST['dateOfBirth'];

if (!empty($fname)) {
    echo "First Name is not empty! <br>";
} else {
    die("First Name is empty! <br>");
}

if (!empty($dateOfBirth)) {
    echo "Date of Birth is not empty! <br>";
} else {
    die("Date of Birth is empty! <br>");
}
```

to make it work the way you want.